# Get list of files changed recently in rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I want to check for all the views files that have been changed in one pull request and save a screenshot of their rendering in a browser. I have system tests to do so but I'm not sure how I can get the files changed. Basically, I want to get a UI check before the changes are merged in the main branch. Is there any way to check this locally using rails tests or else any script that I can run on the submitted PR?
CI - GitHub actions CI
for screenshots - selenium + capybara

Comment: You're going to need to define “recently” more precisely.  Is it in this branch or PR, or do you have other criteria?  What CI system are you using?  Additionally, what does your existing tooling for generating screenshots of page rendering look like (show us commands, code, etc.)?  People will need to know that to provide a good answer.

Comment: @bk2204 I have updated the question, for code you can refer to [Public Lab](https://github.com/publiclab/plots2)